# Porting java to javascript : examples, techniques, best practices?

Tags: java, javascript, porting

I have made a java application with a swing GUI, that I would like to port to the web using javascript.

I know it is a very broad question and I am aware of the fact this can be done many ways.

This means indeed clientside. The data would be supplied by php calls using ajax and the way data is kept (files, database, yet other services) is of no importance.

Has someone experience with this that can point out the possible caveats?
Can someone point out examples, stuff like that?

I realize this might be an too open question, but then again, I am really interested in some case studies or experiences of fellowprogrammers.

Also : if there's a better place to ask this in stackexchange, feel fee to let me know.

UPDATE  : After reading answers so far : Is there anybody out here that has experience with WebCream and would like to share it?

Comment: at the closers : fair enough I suppose, but be helpful and let me know where this very real question belongs

Comment: First thing to get clear on: Java and JavaScript are hardly similar at all. There are some superficial resemblances, but there are **huge** differences.

Comment: @pointy : I am very aware of that, I know Java reasonably well (studied it), and know a thing of 2 about javascript too (closures, different scoping, functional aspects...)  I could have asked : lisp to javascript as well, it's a coincidence that for my needs both languagues sound alike..

Comment: OK, well that's good then.  Many people make the sad mistake of trying to force JavaScript to be like Java, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, a huge historical mistake to name it that way.  That along with similar syntax and the confusion is almost inevetable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some tools that let you convert your Swing application to web application. One of them would be [WebCream](http://www.creamtec.com/webcream/).
Apart from that, [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) to some extent resembles the way you create application in Swing. It would be a lot of rewriting and conversion won't be automatic, but with a large dose of passion it can be done.

Comment: If it does what the screenshots promises... Very very impressing.

Answer (score 1):

you can comunicate php and java for a first appproach, see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/java.examples-basic.php) and have a look at this, [Faster PHP through JAVA](http://www.caucho.com/articles/quercus.pdf)

Comment: +1 : since I find this very informative, but not really an answer though

Comment: Ah, I misundestood the question, sorry.